# How do I find a value of an item in an array by Name (or value) instead of Index?

Tags: c#, arrays

How do I find a value of an item in an array by Name (or value) instead of Index?
For instance; get Name where `ID = 1`

I have an array of objects, in which each object has a sub-array. I want to sort alphabetically where the ID is in the parent object and the Name is in the sub-array…

Each object in the parent array (MyObjects) is shaped like this;

```
Index, _itemID, _price, NamesIDs []
```

The child array in each object (MyObjects._aSingleAssignment.NamesIDs) is shaped like this;

```
Index, _ itemID, _name
```

I didn’t build this thing, so excuse the insanity, but the parent array has Item ID and Price, the sub-array has a list of ALL Item IDs and Names in the system…  For any given ID (parent array), how do I get its Name (sub-array)?

I know how to get _itemID at any given index;

```
MyControl _aSingleAssignment = this.MyObjects[i] as MyControl;
int _itemID = _aSingleAssignment.ID; // The ID for the currently evaluated item
```

I know how to get the Name from any given Index in the sub-array;

```
string _itemName = _aSingleAssignment.NamesIDs[i].Name;
```

But how do I get the Name when given the ID instead of pulling it out by Index?  If I pull it by index I have to iterate through each item in the sub-array and do a compare.  I don’t mind iterating, but I figure there has to be an easier way.

I want to do something like:

`string _itemName = _aSingleAssignment.NamesIDs[ID == _itemID].Name;`

Where is just grabs the name that matches the ID.

The point of this exercise is to sort my parent array alphabetically instead of numerically (.sort())

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please also attach code of the objects you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use LINQ:

```
var foundObj = this.MyObjects.OfType<MyControl>()
                             .Where(n=>n.ID == _itemID)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you have multiple items with same ID you should call `.ToList()` insted of `.FirstOrDefault()`

If you want to sort elements alphabetacally - use `.OrderBy()` extention method:

```
var sorted = this.MyObjects.OfType<MyControl>()
                                 .OrderBy(n=>n.Name)
                                 .ToList();
```

Look at following links for more information:

[LINQ: .NET Language-Integrated Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)

[101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

[LINQPad - Handy utility for learning LINQ](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: You should use `OfType<T>` instead of cast

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the following is on the right track; .Where(n => n.ID == MyObjects.PriceLevels[i].ID) because it should match the parent ID with the sub-array ID.  But once it finds that parent ID it should return the Name.  I'll study those links about LINQ and come back. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexey Aza - Thank you so much for you help.  I studied LINQ and found out I need to ask a much different question.  I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496107/linq-join-and-orderby-issues   I tried to delete this question but can't figure out how...  But thanks!