# LINQ join and orderby issues

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

OK, I've been banging my head against this for a few days, and after studying LINQ I think I am on the right track.  But I have a SQL brain and that is sometimes hard to translate to C#.

I have two arrays, one sorted alphabetically, and the other ordered by ID.  I need to order the second array alphabetically. The IDs are the joining factor. I.E. A.ID = P.ID.

Here are my arrays and example values;

```
private IGenericListItem[] _priceLevels = new IGenericListItem[0];
_priceLevels is in the form of {ID, Name}
{3, A}
{8, B}
{4, C}
{7, D}
{5, E}
{9, F}
{1, G}
```

**Edit:** updated this to show _assignmentControls contains a sub array. I didn't make it so excuse the insanity.  It actually contains a copy of _priceLevels...

```
protected ArrayList _assignmentControls = new ArrayList();
_assignmentControls is in the form of {ID, LastPrice, NewPrice, _priceLevels[]}
{1, 1.00, 2.00, _priceLevels}
{2, 1.00, 2.00, _priceLevels}
{3, 1.00, 2.00, _priceLevels}
{4, 1.00, 2.00, _priceLevels}
```

Part of the problem as that I'm trying to compare/join an ArrayList and an IGenericListItem.

```
In SQL I would do something like this;
SELECT A.* 
FROM _assignmentControls A JOIN _priceLevels P
    ON A.ID = P.ID
ORDER BY P.Name
```

This Returns me an _assignmentControls table sorted by the values in _priceLevels.

In C# LINQ I got this far, but can't seem to get it right;

```
        var sortedList =
            from a in _assignmentControls
            join p in _priceLevels on a equals p.ID
            orderby p.Name
            select _assignmentControls;
```

I am getting red squigglies under join and orderby and the p in p.Name is red. 
And A) it doesn't work. B) I'm not sure it will return sortedList as a sorted version of _assignmentControls sorted by _priceLevels.Name.

EDIT: When I hover over "join" I get "The type arguments for the method 'IEnumerable System.Linq.Enumerable.Join(this Enumerable,IEnumerable, Func,Func....'cannot be infered from the query.  I am researching that now.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Change `a` in the join to `a.ID`.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance - I changed to: join p in _priceLevels on a.ID equals p.ID and the a in a.ID is now red too.  That confuses me because I should be able to reference that field of the ArrayList.

Comment: I think you need select a at the end

Comment: Use a strongly typed `List<T>` instead of an array list, and afaik it should be solved now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I hover over "join" I get "The type arguments for the method `IEnumerable System.Linq.Enumerable.Join(this Enumerable,IEnumerable, Func,Func....` cannot be infered from the query.

I can explain what is going on here so that you can track it down.

When you say

```
from firstitem in firstcollection
join seconditem in secondcollection on firstkey equals secondkey
select result
```

the compiler translates that into:

```
Enumerable.Join(
    firstcollection,
    secondcollection, 
    firstitem=>firstkey, 
    seconditem=>secondkey, 
    (firstitem, seconditem)=>result)
```

`Enumerable.Join` is a generic method that has four type parameters: the element type of the first collection, the element type of the second collection, the key type, and the result type.

If you're getting that error then one of those four things cannot be deduced given the information you've provided to the compiler. For example, maybe:

- The type of the first collection is not actually a sequence.
- The type of the second collection is not actually a sequence.
- The type of the result cannot be deduced
- The two keys are of inconsistent types and there is no unique best type.

That last point is the most likely one. Suppose for example the first key is `int` and the second key is `short`. Since every `short` can be converted to `int`, `int` would win, and the second key would be automatically converted to `int`.  Now suppose that the first key type is `Giraffe` and the second key type is `Tiger`. Neither is better than the other. C# does not say "oh, they're both kinds of `Animal`, so let's pick that."  Rather, it says that you haven't provided enough information to determine which one you meant; you should cast one of them to `Animal` and then it becomes clear.

Make sense?

There's a half-hour video of me explaining this feature back in 2006 -- this was back when I was adding the feature in question to the compiler -- so if you want a more in-depth explanation, check it out.

http://ericlippert.com/2006/11/17/a-face-made-for-email-part-three/

UPDATE: I just read your question again more carefully:

> Part of the problem as that I'm trying to compare/join an `ArrayList` and an `IGenericListItem`.

There's the problem. The type of the sequence cannot be determined from an `ArrayList`. You should not use `ArrayList` anymore. In fact, you should not use it in any code written after 2005.  Use `List<T>` for some suitable T.

Comment: This is a very informative answer, thanks. Now I am struggling with types, but I'll get it. I'm trying to figure out how to get both my ArrayList and IGenericListItem cast as the same type. Thanks!

Comment: @BClaydon: The two sequences do not need to be of the same type. They need to be *generic sequence types*, that is `IEnumerable<something>` but the two "somethings" can be different. What needs to be the same are the *key selector types*.  Think about it this way: if you have a list of customers and a list of orders, it's fine that the two lists are of different types: customer and order. But the selector which *joins* the lists has to be the same: say, a customer has a field Id and an order has a field CustomerId -- the join key type has to be the same on both sides.

Answer (score 4):

Your `select` clause is wrong, it should be like this:

```
    var sortedList =
        from a in _assignmentControls
        join p in _priceLevels on a equals p.ID
        orderby p.Name
        select a;
```

Another issue is that `_assignmentControls` is of type `ArrayList`, which has elements of type `Object`, so the compiler doesn't know the actual type of `a`, and can't use it as the join criteria since `a` doesn't have the same type as `p.ID`.

You should use a `List<int>` (assuming `p.ID` is of type `int`) instead of `ArrayList`. Another option is to specify the type of `a` explicitly:

```
    var sortedList =
        from int a in _assignmentControls
        join p in _priceLevels on a equals p.ID
        orderby p.Name
        select a;
```

Comment: You are correct, I left this out, but _assignmentControls does have objects.  It actually contains a copy of _priceLevels, which is quite obnoxious.
protected ArrayList _assignmentControls = new ArrayList();
_assignmentControls is in the form of {ID, LastPrice, NewPrice, _priceLevels[]}
{1, 1.00, 2.00, _priceLevels}
{2, 1.00, 2.00, _priceLevels}
{3, 1.00, 2.00, _priceLevels}
Earlier I tried using only _assignmentControls and using it's child array of _priceLevels but couldn't figure that out either.  _priceLevels is also a local variable I figured I use the variable.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should write:

```
var sortedList =
                from a in _assignmentControls
                join p in _priceLevels on a.ID equals p.ID
                orderby p.AnotherValue
                select a;
```

When you write from a in _assignmentControls - you are declaring a variable that refers to current element in a sequance that the operation to be performed on. And when you're calling select - you're projecting element from the sequence. Imagine it like conveyer.

Let me give you some example with dump data:

```
public class SomeCLass
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class AnotherClass
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int Value { get; set; }
            public int AnotherValue { get; set; }
        }

public void TestMEthod()
        {
            List<SomeCLass> _assignmentControls = new List<SomeCLass>()
                {
                    new SomeCLass() { ID = 1, Name = "test"},
                    new SomeCLass() { ID = 2, Name = "another test"}
                };
            List<AnotherClass> _priceLevels = new List<AnotherClass>()
                {
                    new AnotherClass() {ID = 1, AnotherValue = 15, Value = 13},
                    new AnotherClass() {ID = 2, AnotherValue = 5, Value = 13}
                };


            var sortedList =
            //here you're declaring variable a that will be like caret when you going through _assignmentControls
            from a in _assignmentControls
            join p in _priceLevels on a.ID equals p.ID
            orderby p.AnotherValue
            select a;


            foreach (var someCLass in sortedList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(someCLass.Name);
            }
        }
```

Result:

```
another test
test
```